# Using Arduino Leonardo with HC-05 to send string to PC with HC-05

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am currently working on making the computer and the arduino board communicate with bluetooth module hc-05 connect on each.

However, my program can show the string, which is counting the seconds, on the serial monitor of the arduino IDE.  But when I unplugged the USB cable providing power to the arduino board and replace it with the 9V battery, the Tx LED on the board keeps turning on and when I open the tera term tuning to the correct baud rate, nothing shows up.

Here is the arduino code I used copied from [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-2-Way-Bluetooth-Connection-Between-Arduino-a/?ALLSTEPS).

```
int counter =0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  delay(50);
}

void loop() {
  counter++;
  Serial.print("Arduino counter: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  delay(500); // wait half a sec
}
```

I am really new to Arduino, only started for a week.  I really sincerely hope that you guys can provide help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Serial1 but not Serial for bluetooth on Leonardo. Serial is for the USB only on Leonardo.